# How to access the date and time a file was created?

Tags: java

How can I get the date and time a file was created in two separate strings? 
I tried using

`Date lastModDate = new Date(mChosenFile.lastModified());`,

but it was deprecated.

Comment: Nothing is deprecated in what you posted. Post the complete and exact error message you get. Also, do you really think a method named "lastModified" returns the "creation" time of a file?

Comment: Which method is deprecated? Date constructor isn't, neither file.lastModified()...

Comment: Unless somehow you're converting the result of `lastModified` to a `String` (and yes, [that particular constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(java.lang.String)) *is* deprecated), I don't see how you're running into any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creation time isn't available via the existing `java.io.File` class, instead, you will need to make use of the newer `Paths` API...

```
Path path = Paths.get(file.toURI());
BasicFileAttributes attributes = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
FileTime creationTime = attributes.creationTime();
Date date = new Date(creationTime.toMillis());
```

You can then use a `DateFormater` to format the `Date` value, for example...

```
String datePart = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(lastModDate);
String timePart = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(lastModDate);
```

Or use a `SimpleDateFormat` to produce custom formats depending on what you need.

Take a look at [Managing Metadata (File and File Store Attributes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html) and [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Many methods in java.util.Date are deprecated for a good reason, they're not very flexible or are flat-out dangerous, like `setDate()`. Use a `java.text.DateFormat` instead.

```
Date lastModDate = new Date(mChosenFile.lastModified()); // nothing wrong here
String datePart = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(lastModDate);
String timePart = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(lastModDate);
```

Comment: Point to the specific part in the Javadoc where it says that constructing a date with a long is deprecated.

Comment: Wasn't explicitly included it in the question, I'm assuming the deprecation was referring to the getDate() and getTime() functions in java.util.Date()

Comment: ...and where in the question are those being used?  What are you getting at?